# MYSQL Server shows it is master server in replication. How to turn off this?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, replication

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 version. I have installed MySQL server using `apt-get install mysql-server` and used `mysql_secure_installation` for security. Then I have installed phpMyAdmin using `apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

Opening phpMyAdmin's status tab shows `This MySQL server works as master in replication process`

[image: Screenshot of Status tab in phpMyAdmin]

Can anyone help me to stop this replication process?
I found nothing about this replication in `my.cnf` configuration file.

my.cnf file

```
The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site offers help in database administration type of questions like this one.

Comment: Please login to mysql and run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%bin%';` and show the result in the question. Also, please look for any `.cnf` files in the `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added below segement at the end of the `my.cnf` file.
It solved the problem.

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
```

Currently my `my.cnf` file looks like:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
```

Comment: Looks like you figured out how to disable binary logging yourself. Congratulations !!!

Comment: Thanks for your hint to binary logging variable.

Answer (score 0):

## DISCLAIMER : NOT phpMyAdmin EXPERT

This is not a problem within MySQL itself. What I think is doing this is the fact that your MySQL server instance has binary logging enabled. According to the book [Mastering phpMyAdmin 3.3.x for Effective MySQL Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005CV58L8)

[image: Hey]

Chapter 13 Page 255 has the following (with that status message):

> **Obtaining replication information**
>
> Apart from the Replication menu, other screens in phpMyAdmin inform us about replication-related items.
>
> **Gathering replication status**
>
> By entering the Status panel in Server
> view, we first get a brief message, for example: ***This MySQL server
> works as master in replication process***. For further information about
> replication status on the server, please visit the replication
> section.
>
> There are a few Replication links on this page that show us
> the status variables of either the master or slave servers, and some
> links to get information about how many slave hosts are connected and
> the status of replication in general.
>
> **Replicated databases**
>
> On the master server, having a look at the Databases menu in Server view shows
> us that each database can potentially be replicated, with a green checkmark in the
> Master replication column:

[image: What]

> This is because this server is configured with a binary log and these databases
> are not excluded from replication.

What is even more intriguing is what is says on Page 256:

> Note that a slave server can itself have a binary log; therefore, in this case
> both Master replication and Slave replication columns are shown. This
> means that this slave could in turn be a master server for another slave
> server.

Simply put, because you have binary logging enabled, that message appears. This is true whether the box is a Replication Master, Replication Slave, or a Standalone server.

If you want that message to disappear, you can go to `my.cnf` and remove the option

```
log-bin
```

Then, restart mysql. Binary logging will be disabled. The message should disappear.

Again, I am not a phpMyAdmin expert. I hope this works for you.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: There is nothing like ``log-bin``